# Validações de endereço / classe / método

Tags: php, validação

### Cenário

Utilizo um método para instanciar classes e métodos dinamicamente.

Propriedades recebidas:

- `modulo` = nome da **pasta** com os arquivos `.class.php`
- `ferramenta` = nome do **arquivo** `.class.php`
- `acao` = nome do **método**

Método que executa a solicitação:

```
private function executar()
{
    try {
        # Monta o patch e faz require da classe
        $classe     = DIR_MODULOS . $this -> modulo . DS . $this -> ferramenta . '.class.php';
        require_once $classe;
        # Instancia o objeto e executa o método
        $obj        = new $this -> ferramenta();
        $resposta   = $obj -> {$this -> acao}($this -> dados);
        # Retorna a resposta
        $this -> retorno = $resposta;

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            $this -> error =  $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

---

### Problemas

- Se a propriedade `modulo` vier incorreta, não irá achar o caminho da pasta.

  - Erro: *Warning* e *Fatal Error* de *require*.
- Se a propriedade `ferramenta` vier incorreta, não irá achar o arquivo da classe.

  - Erro: *Warning* e *Fatal Error* de *require*.
- Se a propriedade `acao` vier incorreta, não irá achar o método na classe.

  - Erro: Erro na chamada do método: *Fatal error:  Call to undefined method*

---

### Dúvida

- Qual a melhor forma de tratar os erros já que o `try-catch` não os trata?

  (de preferência, funções nativas)

---

### Objetivo

A ideia é retornar apenas uma *string* simples conforme o erro.

Exemplo:

- "Módulo inválido"
- "Ferramenta inválida"
- "Ação inválida"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver utilizando o `file_exists`, `class_exists` e `method_exists`.

PS: Como citado pelo Maniero, por ser dinâmico poderá trazer falhas de segurança. No meu caso tratadas antes de chegar a esse método, mas segurança nunca é muito.

---

Como ficou:

```
private function executar()
{
    # Verifica ...
    if (...) {

        # Verifica propriedades mínimas
        if (...) {

            # Monta o path do diretório
            $dir  = DIR_MODULOS . $this -> modulo;
            # Verifica se existe o diretório
            if (file_exists($dir)) {

                # Monta o path do arquivo
                $classe  = DIR_MODULOS . $this -> modulo . DS . $this -> ferramenta . '.class.php';
                # Verifica se existe o arquivo
                if (file_exists($classe)) {

                    # Inclui a classe
                    require_once $classe;
                    # Verifica se existe a classe no arquivo
                    if (class_exists($this -> ferramenta)) {

                        # Cria objeto
                        $obj = new $this -> ferramenta();
                        # Verifica se o método existe
                        if (method_exists($obj, $this -> acao)) {

                            # Executa o método
                            $retorno = $obj -> {$this -> acao}($this -> dados);
                            # Retorna a resposta
                            $this -> retorno = $retorno;

                        } else {
                            $this -> error = "Ação inexistente.";
                        }

                    } else {
                        $this -> error = "Ferramenta inválida 2.";
                    }

                } else {
                    $this -> error = "Ferramenta inválida 1.";
                }

            } else {
                $this -> error = "Módulo inválido.";
            }

        } else {
            $this -> error = "Erro na estrutura JSON.";
        }

    } else {
        $this -> error = "Erro ...!";
    }

}
```

---

Links úteis:

[file_exists](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php)

[class_exists](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.class-exists.php)

[method_exists](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.method-exists.php)

Comment: Um detalhe: `file_exists` não garante que a classe existe.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Mas o "modulo" e "ferramenta" é o que compõe o caminho. Então se não existir algum dos 2, já dá erro. E a classe tem o mesmo nome do arquivo. Exemplo: "Producao.class.php", a classe é "Producao".

Comment: E se o arquivo `Producao.class.php` existir mas não possuir a classe `Producao`?

Comment: Então, por isso a classe tem o prefixo do arquivo: " E a classe tem o mesmo nome do arquivo. Exemplo: "Producao.class.php", a classe é "Producao" ". Como a classe é a "ferramenta", o que mudará serão somente os métodos ("acao").

Comment: Mas isso não te previne de erro do programador, que define a classe "Produgato" dentro do arquivo "Producao.class.php". Será interessante verificar a existência da classe com `class_exists` também.

Comment: Boa, verdade! Implementado!

Answer (score 2):

O uso de `try-catch` aí já é errado. Eu respondo isso em [várias perguntas aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A101%20%5Bexce%C3%A7%C3%A3o%5D) (recomendo seguir os *links* fortemente). Não capture `Exception` a não ser na saída final do código e não capture uma exceção para fazer nada útil.

O que está reportando é um erro de programação, e erros de programação a gente corrige e não tenta se recuperar. Exceção é para se recuperar de uma falha não esperada, mas não um erro de programação.

Em códigos de natureza dinâmica, e em linguagem de tipagem dinâmica tudo é mais ou menos de natureza dinâmica, você deve verificar o que vai usar antes de usar. A verificação só não precisa ser feita onde é garantido que dará certo.

O erro de programação aí é não considerar que o dado pode vir errado. Então antes de usar algo com potencial de estar errado verifique se está certo e decida o que fazer se estiver errado. Só execute se tudo está correto. Quase sempre o `if` é seu amigo.

Quem sabe um dia eu escreva um livro sobre o assunto :). Sim, para dominar exceção e tratamento de erro precisa de um livro. Por isso mesmo a maioria das pessoas não vão aprender, quase todo mundo hoje em dia não quer ler, não quer gastar tempo aprendendo, faz o que é simples, mesmo que seja errado e se funcionar, tá bom. É bem complicado tratar erros corretamente, e mais ainda usar exceção. Uma coisa que sempre falo é que se não domina um recurso, não o use, e este é o caso da exceção, por isso tenho uma palestra chama "Exceção - o goto do século XXI" já que é o mecanismo que mais causa problemas para as pessoas, causa muito mais que o `goto` que todo mundo sabe que não é para usar.

Comment: Entendi o que quis dizer, mas eu gosto de tratar qualquer "possível" erro, mesmo que ainda serei eu que farei as requisições. Mas gostaria de deixar o retorno o mais simples possível. O "modulo" e "ferramenta" já estou tratando com o `file_exists`, ainda não olhei o "acao" que é a solicitação de método. A ideia seria tratar eles, não quero mudar o código. Poderei ter erro de digitação, então por que não facilitar o retorno do motivo do erro!?

Comment: Dependendo de como faz você tem um enorme buraco de segurança. Gosto eu não discuto, eu falo sempre do que é o certo, quando se faz por gosto ,qualquer coisa serve.

Comment: Concordo, quanto mais dinâmico, maior possíveis falhas. Mas essas vou tratar numa camada anterior, considerando que se passar dela, poderá executar o restante.